# jQuery Scroll Multiple divs (.scrollLeft) Not Working on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I'm trying to debug some old jQuery code that someone wrote. It works fine in all browsers except the iPad. The goal is that there are two separate divs: a header row and then a div that contains many body rows (in a table).

Here's a sample of the front-end code (I did not write it, I know there are some semantic issues):

```
<div class="detailsScroller" id="headerDetailsScroller" style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="scrollingDetailsContainer" style="width: 935px; ">
    <table class="alternating scrollingDetails" id="headerScrollingDetails">
        <thead>
            <tr class="even">
                <td>[Header Rows Here]</td>
                …
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="detailsScroller">
    <div class="scrollingDetailsContainer" style="width: 935px; ">
        <table class="alternating scrollingDetails" id="scrollingDetailsTable">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>[Content Here]</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    …
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when the second set of `<div>s` is scrolled, the first set should scroll alongside. It could go left or right. This is accomplished through this jQuery code:

```
$("#fakeHorizontalScroller").scroll(function(thing) {
    $("#headerDetailsScroller").scrollLeft(($(thing.target).scrollLeft()));
    $("div.detailsScroller").scrollLeft(($(thing.target).scrollLeft()));
});
```

The only thing I've managed to come across in my research is that .scrollLeft doesn't work on Mobile Safari. Is there a suitable alternative, or another way to approach this? All the solutions I've found are forcing an animation to move to a particular spot on an event. I simply want both `<div>s` to track each other as you scroll left and right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the fix. Looks like I need to use the on scroll event. This took care of the problem:

```
$("div.detailsScroller").on('scroll', function() {
    $("#headerDetailsScroller").scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
})
```